# Using R to remove all columns that sum to 0

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a very large CSV file containing counts of unique DNA sequences, and there is a column for each unique sequence. I started with hundreds of samples and cut it down to only 15 that I care about but now I have THOUSANDS of columns that contain nothing but Zeroes and it is messing up my data processing. How do I go about completely removing any column that sums to zero? I’ve seen some similar questions on here but none of those suggestions have worked for me.

I have 6653 columns and 16 rows in my data frame.

If it matters my columns all have super crazy names, some several hundred characters long ( AATCGGCTAA..., etc) and the row names are the sample IDs which are also not entirely numeric. Any tips greatly appreciated. I am still new to R so please let me know where I will need to change things in code examples if you can! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `colSums`

```
set.seed(10)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.8, .2)), 
                           5, 10))

df
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
# 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
# 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
# 5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1

df[colSums(df) != 0]
#   V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V10
# 1  0  1  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  1  0  1   0
# 3  0  0  0  0  1   0
# 4  0  0  0  1  0   0
# 5  1  0  0  0  0   1
```

But you might not want to remove all columns which sum to 0, because that could be true even if not all elements are 0. Take `V4` in the data frame below as an example.

```
df$V4[1] <- -1
df
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
# 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
# 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
# 5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
```

So if you want to only remove columns where all elements are 0, you can do

```
df[colSums(df == 0) < nrow(df)]
#   V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V10
# 1 -1  1  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  1  0  1   0
# 3  0  0  0  0  1   0
# 4  0  0  0  1  0   0
# 5  1  0  0  0  0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO here is a tidyverse approach

```
library(tidyverse)


mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  select_if(~ sum(.x) > 0)
```